# Load gallery with link Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, gallery

This is my first post so please be patient :)

I started a few days ago with making a wallpaper app. 
I want to load my images from a plogger album (rss-media) how can I do that?

I don't want to load my images one by one but in one step is that possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Need to create asynctask with loading images and do loop from all pic links with calling the asynctask.

```
    LoadPic pic = new LoadPic();
    pic.link = link;
    pic.execute("");



    private class LoadPic extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        public String link;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
        String response = "";

        return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That url points at media rss. You'll need to create an xml parser that can parse that RSS feed. There are many ways to do that, but [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/parsing-xml-with-xmlpullparser-2/) is a simple one similar to your use case. You could take that example and modify it to use your url and have it look for media:content elements which contain your urls. You'll need to parse out all the urls from that RSS feed and then load them
2. You can't load multiple images in one step. You need to move the data from each desired image url to the device and the load a gallery or imageview with the result.

Comment: Oke thanks already for your help but as I said earlier I still don't know a lot about it. So I make a new activity called xmlPullParser with the code in your link or can I add it in my 'MainActivity'? And then do I have to load my images one by one like image_URL="http://..."?

Comment: I'd try to get that code just to printout the urls you want first before you worry about loading them. If you put a Log.d("TEST", ) inside the event code of the link i provided, try to modify that code so it prints the urls. Then next try to make a list of all the urls and then try to load them. Unfortunately, each url will have to be loaded individually. There is no way around this.